# Want to display every activity on wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all website related activity on my word-press homepage. Means if any user register or comment on any post that will display on homepage. i goggling but i thinks i did not find relevant solutions.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: you need to go to some effort to find a solution before asking here, wordpress have their own support forums which can be searched but I think you will find the solution in their own help pages - it could be done via a widget or plug-in for instance. Here is what is expected for posters on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: suppose if i want to display bbpress activity is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can not find any solution because what you are asking is very broad and depends on what you really want .

In general you would have to use [filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) or [hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x) .

for the two examples you have specifically asked :

For **User registration** :

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_action', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_action( $user_id ) {

    // here you put the funtion that you want ....

}
```

Details here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

for **Comments insertion** :

```
add_action('wp_insert_comment','comment_inserted',99,2);

function comment_inserted($comment_id, $comment_object) {
    if ($comment_object->comment_parent > 0) {
        //do what you want ..
    }
}
```

More here :https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment

Basically in those functions you will have to set some flag somewhere in the database for latest actions, and then call it in your theme ..
There are so many ways to do that , but basically, like I said before, it is really depending on the specifics and details of what you want .